# If the contents have been rendered to the browser, why does the app stop 'working' when I stop "ng serve"?

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, frontend

I am trying to understand front-end technology in general. 
How does 'ng serve' work in Angular 2: considering scenario where we have routing, event emitters and listeners. Who processes these 'requests'?
If all this is done by the browser engine, does it mean that all of the content (HTML + JavaScript + CSS) has been delivered to the browser? In that case, the app should still work as long as the browser is open.

Comment: Perhaps it's browsersync that tries to keep the connection. What does "stop 'working'" mean? This doesn't provide much useful information. If you try it with the build output with some production HTTP server it will work as long as the code doesn't make any server requests.

Comment: By "stops working", I mean that the requests to get data from firebase does not happen. If I switch to another tab (module) in my application, but the contents (from firebase) are not loaded.
Follow-up question: Connection between what? I have a pure Angular 2 app which does not have send any server requests. 
Going back to the same question, if the browser loads all HTML+JS as soon as we visit the URL, why do I need to have ng serve running?

Comment: Please try it with another server so that browsersync is out of the equation. I don't have that setup here to try it myself.